# OpenGL games won't open due to X11

Tags: games, opengl, x11, sdl

For some reason, any OpenGL game I try to play crashes when it wants to open the window. Let me give you an example from running `teeworlds` from terminal:

```
imnotanerd@sys76laptop:~$ teeworlds
# skip to the error
[5015be1f][gfx]: unable to set video mode: X11 driver not configured with OpenGL   
[5015be1f][gfx]: out of ideas. failed to init graphics
```

That X11 error will pop up with any OpenGL game I open. I've been researching this (Without much luck) and have seen that I should install SDL. Ok, so on to libsdl.org, download source, `./configure && make && make install`, no errors with that, and the same error still shows. Any ideas on how to finally fix this?

Comment: What graphics card do you have? Does your laptop have a hybrid graphics solution?\

Comment: My laptop is running HD 4000 on an i7.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer on [this page](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1486851). In case you don't feel like clicking here's the tl;dr:

From the SDL directory you downloaded:
`sudo make uninstall ; ./configure --prefix=/usr ; sudo make ; sudo make install`